# Running jquery script after shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode, jquery

I'm really new to wordpress and now I have to do a plugin that creates a HTML table from file and prints it to the page, and add more functionality to the table using DataTables jquery addon. This all has to happen when i call shortcode in the page. I have managed to get the html table to the page, but i have no idea how to run jquery script to modify it. 
So, in short: how to run jquery script after shortcode. 
Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You question is not very clear. A shortcode is evaluated on the server side. The page is then sent to the user, including any scripts. So the script will always be applied after the shortcode.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear. I'm interpreting it to mean that you want to enqueue a jQuery script to be run by the user's browser only on public pages that contain the shortcode.

There are (at least) three ways of running a jQuery script only on pages that have a specific shortcode. The first way is to use the `add_shortcode()` function to add a hook to `get_footer` which then enqueues the jQuery script in the footer.

```
//* Enqueue script in the footer
function wpse_260465_enqueue_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'your-style-id', PATH_TO . 'script.js', [ 'jquery' ], false, true );
}

//* Add action to enqueue script in the footer and return shortcode value
function wpse_260465_shortcode( $atts ) {
  add_action( 'get_footer', 'wpse_260465_enqueue_script' );
  return 'your shortcode content';
}

add_shortcode( 'wpse_260465', 'wpse_260465_shortcode' );
```

The second way registers the script on every page, but only enqueues it when the specific shortcode is called on a page.

```
//* Enqueue previously registered script and return shortcode value
function wpse_260465_shortcode( $atts ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'your-style-id' );
  return 'your shortcode content';
}
add_shortcode( 'wpse_260465', 'wpse_260465_shortcode' );

//* Register our script to maybe enqueue later
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_260465_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse_260465_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'your-style-id', PATH_TO . 'script.js', [ 'jquery' ], false, true );
}
```

The third way is to simply use the `add_shortcode()` function to write the jQuery inline.

```
//* Return inline jQuery script with shortcode value
function wpse_260465_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $your_shortcode_content = 'your shortcode content';
  $your_shortcode_content .= $your_inline_jquery;
  return $your_shortcode_content;
}
add_shortcode( 'wpse_260465', 'wpse_260465_shortcode' );
```

The first and second methods are more the "WordPress way", and the third is the easiest to understand, but all three should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_css_and_js() {
    wp_register_style('your_css_and_js', plugins_url('style.css',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('your_css_and_js');
    wp_register_script( 'your_css_and_js', plugins_url('your_script.js',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('your_css_and_js');
}

//adds to the admin dasboard if needed
add_action( 'admin_init','your_css_and_js');

//adds to frontend
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_css_and_js');
```